# Ng-include partial not rendering with phantomjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, seo, phantomjs, mean-stack

So, I am using the MEAN stack and my landing page includes a number of Angular ng-include's. For example:

```
<div data-ng-include="'/modules/landing/views/sections/features.client.view.html'">
```

I'm also using mean-seo: https://github.com/meanjs/mean-seo. This essentially just uses phantomjs to render the page if a crawler is detected via ?_escaped_fragment_=.

My problem is that the partials being included via the ng-include are not rendered by mean-seo, i.e. by phantomjs.

If you have any ideas why this might be it would be terrific if you could share them!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this to work using prerender.io. I'm still not certain why it wasn't working when I was taking a DIY approach...